# SAS numeric date format to dd/mm/yy

Tags: sas

Hi really basic question regarding SAS.

My data set has the date format yyyymmdd and the type is numeric. I want to convert the column so that the dates will be dd/mm/yyyy. Probably a very basic code but I'm very new to SAS.

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where is your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
proc sql;
alter table <library.table>
modify <column> format=ddmmyys10.;
quit;
```

For slash separator, there's "s" in ddmmyys10. format.

Alternatively:

```
proc datasets lib=<library> nolist nodetails;
modify <table>;
format <column> ddmmyys10.;
quit;
```

Comment: I've been able to use this hope to some success, thanks for the help. Would you have any suggestions if the format is datetime15.? So far its stored as   30NOV94:00:00 and I like it in the format ddmmyys10. but for some reason it always ends up transforming the date into some long number in the millions.

Comment: If the current format is datetime., it's highly probable the *values* represent datetime, not just date. For SAS, datetime value is number of seconds since 1jan1960, while for date it's number of days. So you'll need to "cast" the values from datetime to date by running `proc sql; update <lib>.<table> set <column> = DATEPART(<column>); quit;` After this, ddmmyys10. will display proper dates.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work. Would set vardate = datepart(vardate); be the correct syntax? Or what should I be placing in datepart()?

Comment: `proc sql; update mylib.mytable set vardate = DATEPART(vardate); quit;`

Comment: No luck. Thanks anyway. The code did work...but I think there must be an error with how I've imported the data.